# How do I construct HTTP requests in R for testing?

Tags: r, api, http, testing, request

I've written a small API in R, using `plumber`. (See https://www.rplumber.io/ ) I would like to write a test that can be run against the source code, to verify I get the expected response. I would like the test to pass in a HTTP-request object to the API's endpoint. The usual library for constructing requests seems to be `httr`. (See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html ), but the `request_build` function I'd like to use isn't exposed at the outermost scope.

The relevant Plumber-decorated lines are:

```
#* @post /endpoint
wrapper <- function(req) {
```

Is there a way to access the internal function of a package?  `library(httr)` doesn't give me access to its internal `request_build`)

Alternately, I'm looking at the library `httptest`, but I'm having trouble getting it to generate a request object. (See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httptest/vignettes/httptest.html ) I see that it's supposed to *record* requests for later use, but that's *also* giving me trouble:

```
with_mock_api({ 
    a <- POST("http://127.0.0.1:9999/endpoint", body=list(raw="This is some sample text."), config=list("content-type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
    print(a)
})


Error: POST http://127.0.0.1:9999/endpoint list(raw = "This is some sample text.") (127.0.0.1-9999/endpoint-93904a-POST.json)
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here; Postman ( https://www.getpostman.com/ ) confirms the API is up and functioning.

Also, is it possible to record multiple requests and specify which I want during test? I'm currently using `testthat`, but I haven't found any capabilities well-suited to constructing / mocking HTTP requests. (See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html )

Comment: Are you familiar with `rvest`?

Comment: What are you unable to do exactly that you think you need `request_build` for? How can we test and verify possible solutions?

Comment: another option is https://github.com/ropensci/vcr  but only works with https://github.com/ropensci/crul for now (`httr` support to come) - nearly ready for first cran push on `vcr` - would love any feedback

Comment: @MrFlick Plumber decorates a function which takes a request as its input.  I'm trying to test that function, `request_build` is the function `httr` uses to construct a request, so it seemed like an obvious choice.  I'm open to suggestions if there's another function that does something similar.

Comment: @Hackerman I hadn't heard of `rvest` before, but https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf seems more focused on scraping web-pages and their metadata than on testing or the HTTP process itself.

Comment: @sckott Thanks for the recommendation on `vcr`. (I thought I was the only person on Stack Overflow old enough to catch the reference.) I will look at it and the packages it references: `crul` and `webmockr`.  (I'm still very new to R. These are all new to me.)

Comment: The docs for `plumber` [clearly show](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/tips-tricks.html#testing) that ... unit testing isn't well-documented yet :-), not what you need. If you're looking for unit-tests for an active API, why not just do the `POST` (sans `with_mock_api`) and compare the output with what you expect? If you want to formalize it, `testthat` (among other testing methodologies) could help. (If I understand it right, `with_mock_api` specifically stops an actual network query, so that may not be what you want.)

Comment: @r2evans I'd like to be able to test the code without standing up a server / container for it. I'm currently using `testthat`. I prefer to be able to test at each function call / change of scope.  Sure, it's possible to stand up the full system, but that seems like more overhead and possible opportunities for something to fail than a unit test would be. All I need to do is construct an appropriate input for a single function. I even know the name of a function which are supposed to be able to construct such an input. The only problem is it's defined in a hard-to-reach scope.

Comment: Currently, `plumber` holds the current process, so it's difficult to automate it. However, if you're comfortable with helper scripts ("setup" scripts, see `?test_dir`) and `parallel`, you can mimic how [`opencpu` forks stuff into the background](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu/blob/146ffd4da21967abb267a6a6d9b454fa5f59d011/R/start.R#L53-L63), start `r$run(port=8000)`, and then work with an active plumber process.

Comment: https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues/249